# Regex for Consecutive Match

Tags: java, regex

I am a newbie in regex and java, so I have been struggling with this problem for a very long time. Does anyone know how to create a regex expression to use with Replace function to replace consecutive matches or just a match with white space delimiter.

Example 1:
string: "aa aa aa aa!"

replace with: "bb"

result: "bb bb bb aa!"

Example 2: 
String: "This is an an ant"

Replace: "@@"

Result: "This is @@ @@ ant"

Example 3: 
String: "This is an ant"

Replace: "@@"

Result: "This is @@ ant"

Thanks,

Comment: use String#replaceAll() method.

Comment: Why is the last  `aa` not replaced?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Because he only wants to replace it if there's whitespace after.

Comment: Still, not clear. Looks like `.replace("aa ", "bb ")` will do.

Comment: Are these matches always at the start of the string? Can there be `aa aa aa cc vv aa aa!` -> `bb bb bb cc vv aa aa!`?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Matches can be anywhere in the string.

Answer (score 0):

you could use the **[replace()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replace(char,%20char))** method of the `String` class:

```
String data = "aa aa aa aa!";
System.out.println(data.replace("aa ", "bb "));
```

result:

```
bb bb bb aa!
```

Comment: Why `replaceAll`? The same can be achieved with `.replace("aa ", "bb ")`.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew true, either way, would work but sure I'll use "replace()" since it's more convenient for this case.

Comment: @Tanpe so you want the result to be "bb bb bb bb!"?

Comment: No the result should be "bb bb bb aa!" Sorry if the question is unclear but I actually want an expression that can replace a consecutive matches. For example, string: "This is an an an ant" replace with "@@" result string "This is @@ @@ @@ ant". and also can replace just one match. For example, String: "This is an ant!" would be "This is @@ ant!"

Answer (score 0):

It seems you are looking for [positive lookahead](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html#special) which matches only if expression A is followed by expression b.

```
String s = "This is an an an ant";
// \\s represents any whitespace
// (?=an) stands for positive lookahead 
String result = s.replaceAll("an\\s(?=an)", "@@ ");
```

Comment: OP means repetition of *any* characters

Answer (score 0):

You seem to want to replace whole words that are followed with a whitespace and the same value right after regardless whether it is a whole word or not.

I'd use

```
s = s.replaceAll("\\b(\\w+)(?=\\s\\1)", "@@");
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/VJH6LH/1).

*Details*:

- `\b` - a leading word boundary
- `(\w+)` - Group 1 capturing a word
- `(?=\s\1)` - a positive lookahead that requires a whitespace (`\s`) followed with the same value stored inside Group 1 (with `\1` backreference).